# updateObject or changeObject, removeObject or deleteObject?

Tags: java, naming-conventions

I'm off starting another project and I'm creating functions to add, update and remove objects.

I tend to doubt myself when it comes to naming the update and remove function, because sometimes i name them:

```
updateObject and removeObject
```

but when i'm in a different mood on a different project i go for:

```
changeObject and deleteObject
```

Is there a naming convention in Java for these crud functions or should i go how i feel when i start a new project?

Comment: I would say that `remove` is usually used, when object is removed from somewhere (e.g. remove user from admins), while `delete` is for the cases when object is destroyed (e.g. delete user).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The point of conventions are to make code consistent and understandable. Whether you call the methods `removeObject`, `deleteObject`, or whatever, they're still going to be very recognizable to anyone reading your code. That being said, I would agree that `update` and `remove` are probably more common than the alternatives.

Answer (score 1):

add, update, remove is generally more prevalent, but as long as you're consistent I don't think it matters.